# Using C# for cgi-bin POST request on an HTML form

Tags: c#, html, post, cgi-bin

I want to save information from a webpage. The user selects a frequency (530 to 1700) from a drop-down and then submits and gets a list back for that frequency. I want to loop through each value, run the query, and (after some parsing and clean-up) save the results to a file. Would prefer to do it in a C# app, but VB or Java are OK, too. I've found a number of ways to get and save the original form page. But nothing about how I can take that page in code and then submit against it to get results back.  Here's the link I'm trying to query and a stripped-down look at the HTML.

```
http://www.topazdesigns.com/ambc/amsearch96a.html
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" href="aminfo.css" rel="STYLESHEET">
  <title>AM Station Search</title>
</head>

<form action="/cgi-bin/amsearch96a.pl" method="post" target="amoutput">
  
  <table style="background-color: rgb(135, 206, 250); width: 100%; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0">
    <tbody>
     
      <tr>
        <td><b>AM Frequency:
        <select size="1" name="freq">
        <option>530
        </option>
        <! etc X 10>
        <option selected="selected">1200
        </option>
        <! etc X 10>
        <option>1700
        </option>
        </select>
        </b> </td>
  
        <td align="right"><input value="Show All Stations" name="B4" class="button" type="submit"> </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    </tbody>
  
  <table style="background-color: rgb(135, 206, 250); width: 100%; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0">

    <tbody>
       <tr>
       <td style="text-align: left;">Include power/antenna info: <input checked="checked" name="pwrant" value="on" type="checkbox"></td>
       <td style="text-align: right;">Include low power (<100W) stations: <input name="lowpwr" value="on" type="checkbox"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    
  </table>  

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to change the forms action "/cgi-bin/amsearch96a.pl" to point to your asp.net app or cgi script or whatever you are writing on the server to handle the form. At the moment it points to a perlscript which I suppose would be part of a tutorial?

Comment: I can't change the form on the webpage or what's behind it. It's someone else's page that I want to get information from. I can load the page but how to submit data with a selected value?

Comment: Submit data to where? If you cant control where the page is being submitted to how do you expect to get the form values?